# using loginById does not switch cart

Tags: magento-1.9, quote

I am using

```php
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginByid(…);
```

in a controller to let a customer log in as a different user (background: customers have "subaccounts" which they can switch to). This works fine for the most part, however **the cart stays connected to the previous user**, i.e. the user you logged into Magento in the first place.

So if you log in as user `A`, add some items to the cart and then switch to user `B`, the cart will still have the items from user `A`. When items are added to the cart, the items in `sales_flat_quote_item` in the database are still assigned to the quote of the previously logged in user.

Is there something special I have to execute to make this work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When switching the user with `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginByid(…)` Magento processes the quote with `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->loadCustomerQuote()`. Here Magento always either keeps using the current quote or it merges the customer quote with the current quote.

Thus, you need to replace the quote yourself, if you want independent carts for each customer you switch to. For example:

```php
// get quote of new customer
$newQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->loadByCustomer( $customerId );

// if there is no new quote or the new quote has the same ID as the current quote
if( !$newQuote->getId() || $newQuote->getId() == Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getId() )
{
    // get the new customer
    $newCustomer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load( $customerId );

    // create new quote
    $newQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->assignCustomer( $newCustomer )
                    ->setIsActive( true )
                    ->save();
}

// replace the quote with the new quote
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->replaceQuote( $newQuote );

// log in new user
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById( $customerId );
```

Comment: You have saved my day. Thank you. It works

Answer (score -1):

this is because your quote data also save in magento session to

you can clear magento quote session data by following code

```
foreach(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
}
```

Comment: But this simply deletes any item from the cart (in the database). So if I login as user `A`, add some items to the cart and login as user `B` and then switch back to user `A`, the previously added cart items will be gone.

Comment: Furthermore any item _added_ to the cart after switching to user `B` will still be assigned to the cart of user `A`. So this does not solve the problem at all.